# SQL Updatable View with joined tables

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-update, sql-view

I have a view that looks similar to this,

```
SELECT  dbo.Staff.StaffId, dbo.Staff.StaffName, dbo.StaffPreferences.filter_type
FROM    dbo.Staff LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.StaffPreferences ON dbo.Staff.StaffId = dbo.StaffPreferences.StaffId
```

I'm trying to update `StaffPreferences.filter_type` using,

```
UPDATE vw_Staff SET filter_type=1 WHERE StaffId=25
```

I have read this in an MSDN article,

> Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements,
>   must reference columns from only one base table.

Does this mean that I can only update fields in dbo.Staff (which is all I can currently achieve) In this context does the definition of 'base table' not extend to any subsequently joined tables?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your statement should work just fine since you are only modifying column(s) from one table (`StaffPreferences`).

If you tried to update a columns from different tables in the same update statement you would get an error.

```
Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
View or function 'v_ViewName' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.
```

Comment: The UPDATE statement runs it just says "(0 row(s) affected)" if I change it to update StaffName I get 1 row affected.

Comment: @Rob2211 that probably means that there are no row in `StaffPreferences` with `StaffID = 25`

Comment: Oh dear, well don't I feel sheepish! I must have assumed it would create that row but why on earth would it!

Comment: In addition to this, you can update multiple rows if you create two `INSTEAD OF INSERT` and `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` triggers which do the inset manipulation manually.

Answer (score 5):

> The rules for updatable join views are as follows:
>
> **General Rule**
>
> Any INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operation on a join view can modify only
>   one underlying base table at a time.
>
> **UPDATE Rule**    All updatable columns of a join view must map to
>   columns of a key-preserved table. See "Key-Preserved Tables" for a
>   discussion of key-preserved tables. If the view is defined with the
>   WITH CHECK OPTION clause, then all join columns and all columns of
>   repeated tables are non-updatable.
>
> **DELETE Rule**
>
> Rows from a join view can be deleted as long as there is exactly one
>   key-preserved table in the join. If the view is defined with the WITH
>   CHECK OPTION clause and the key preserved table is repeated, then the
>   rows cannot be deleted from the view.
>
> **INSERT Rule**    An INSERT statement must not explicitly or
>   implicitly refer to the columns of a nonkey preserved table. If the
>   join view is defined with the WITH CHECK OPTION clause, INSERT
>   statements are not permitted.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/views.htm#391

Comment: `All updatable columns of a join view must map to columns of a key-preserved table.` Is this true of MS SQL, not just oracle?

Comment: As far as I can tell this applies to MSSQL too.

Comment: What is the reason for the "General Rule"?  Could it cause some sort of pathological state?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can see some of the problems that might occur if there's a row in `Staff` with `StaffId` 25, but no matching row in `StaffPreferences`. There are various right things you could do (preserve the appearance that this is a table, perform an insert in `StaffPreferences`; reject the update; etc).

I think at this point, the SQL Server engine will give up, and you'll have to write a trigger that implements the behaviour you want (whatever that may be. You need to consider all of the cases for the join working/not working)

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I solved it.

In my case it was table, not a view, but I needed to find the schema id that referenced the table in the data construction in a reference table, say called `our_schema`.

I ran the following:

```
select schemaid from our_schema where name = "MY:Form"
```

This gave me the id as 778 (example)

Then I looked where this ID was showing up with a prefix of T, B, or H.

In our case we have Table, Base and History tables where the data is stored.

I then ran:

```
delete from T778
delete from B778
delete from H778
```

This allowed me to delete the data and bypass that restriction.